# C# join LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I join multiple tables in LINQ query, but this is much time taken for execution. how can minimize execution time?
this is my code please note. thanks.
removed the join Client table from that joining. and join as single from that data this is taking normal time for execution but why?

```
var invoices = await (
            from log in logsByInvoiceId
            join ticket in filteredTickets
                on log.OldestLog.Ticket equals ticket.Ticket                //use oldest log from grouping of logs with same CobraInvoiceID to track the "status" of each invoice
            join issue in DataContext.SLClientIssueHistoryEntity            //assumes every ticket has at least one issue
                on ticket.Ticket equals issue.Ticket into issueGroup
            join client in DataContext.Client
                on ticket.ClientID equals client.ClientID
            join state in DataContext.SLStateEntity
                on ticket.State equals state.ID
            join invoice in DataContext.CobraInvoiceEntity
                on log.InvoiceId equals invoice.CobraInvoiceID
            where !invoice.IsPaid
            join employee in DataContext.TrackerCobraEdgeEmployeeEnrollmentEntities
                on invoice.EmployeeID equals employee.EmployeeID
            join employeeDataCollection in DataContext.TrackerCobraEdgeDataRecordCollectionEntities     //only one 'DataCollection' per employee
                on employee.EmployeeID equals employeeDataCollection.EmployeeID
            join paymentGroup in paymentsByInvoiceId
                on invoice.CobraInvoiceID equals paymentGroup.InvoiceId into payment
            from pymt in payment.DefaultIfEmpty()                          
            select new CobraServiceModel
            {
                Ticket = ticket.Ticket,
                State = ticket.State,
                CreatedBy = ticket.CreatedBy,
                CreatedDate = ticket.CreatedDate,
                Notes = ticket.Notes,
                ClientID = ticket.ClientID,
                AssignTeam = ticket.AssignTeam,
                AssignTo = ticket.AssignTo,
                AssignToEmail = ticket.AssignToEmail,
                EmailSentDate = ticket.EmailSentDate,
                IsCritical = ticket.IsCritical,
                Source = ticket.Source,
                DueDate = ticket.DueDate,
                Attachment_URL = ticket.Attachment_URL,
                Result = ticket.Result,
                ConclusionStatus = ticket.ConclusionStatus,
                ClientIssue = issueGroup.Select(g => g.IssueID).ToList(),

                ClientEIN = client.EIN,
                ClientName = client.ClientName,
                StateType = state.Type,
                NextPaymentDueDate = invoice.InvoiceDueDate,
                OutstandingBalance = invoice.OutstandingBalance,
                EmployeeFirstName = employee.FirstName,
                EmployeeMiddleName = employee.MiddleName,
                EmployeeLastName = employee.LastName,
                EmployeeEmail = employee.Email,                    EmployeePhone = employee.PhoneNumber,
                CobraEndDate = employeeDataCollection.CobraEndDate,
                LastPaymentReceivedDate = (pymt == null ? null : (DateTime?)pymt.NewestPayment.PaymentDate)
            }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Don't use JOINs. LINQ isn't SQL. You're using an ORM. It's the ORM's job to generate joins from the object relations (the O in ORM), not the developer's. Add proper relation and navigation properties in your classes. If you can't do that, don't use an ORM at all.

Comment: If the query is slow, it means the necessary indexes are missing, the query is loading too much, or the query is doing something that prevents the database from using indexes. We can't tell what the tables look like or if they have indexes. There's no `Where` clause which means the query loads everything. You can inspect the generated SQL and check its execution plan to see what's actually going on

Comment: With properly designed classes this entire query could be as simple as `context.Tickets.Where(t=>t.Id==42);` or, if you want to load multiple tickets, `context.Tickets.Where(t=>ticketIds.Contains(t.Id))`. All related entities, eg assignees, clients etc should be properties on the `Ticket` object, allowing EF to load them with eg `.Include(t=>t.Assignee)` or use them in a `Select` clause, eg `.Select(t=>new {Assignee=t.Assignee.Name,...})`.

Comment: If you want to flatten a complex hierarchy to a flat object to display on a grid, you can use a tool like AutoMapper to generate the `Select` clause by matching types and properties by name, eg map `Assignee.Name` to a property named `AssigneeName`.

Comment: indexes there, And it you mean that I will remove all join queries and use where clause.
but I removed the Client table joining `join client in DataContext.Client
                on ticket.ClientID equals client.ClientID` then it takes time normal. why?

Comment: We can't guess without the table schemas (ie definition and indexes), classes and *data*. Any query performance question is meaningless without the SQL query itself, the execution plan and data statistics (ie number of rows in the tables and results). Perhaps one or both of the ClientID columns isn't indexed. Perhaps the `Client` table has a different Primary Key, and all rows have the same `ClientID` value, eg null, resulting in data explosion

Comment: Which EF version are you using? EF or EF Core?2, 3, 6, 7? Some older versions would use client-side evaluation if they couldn't translate LINQ into SQL - they'd load all intermediate results in memory and filter them there. EF 6 and EF Core 3 and later throw exceptions when they can't translate LINQ into SQL